# Record Not Found Error: Couldn't find List without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a basic to do type app with `lists`, each of which `has_many` `items`. I'm trying to construct a view for delegated tasks (`sharing/tasks.html.erb`) to show `items` that have been marked as delegated. Here is the relevant code on the `tasks.html.erb` page:

```
  <h2 class="text-center">Delegated to Me</h2>
  <% @deligated_to_me.each do |item| %>
      <p><%= link_to list_path(@list) do %>
        <%= item.name %>
      <% end %>
     (Deligated by <%= item.user_id %>)</p>
  <% end %>
```

And here is the `sharing_controller` section for the `tasks` page:

```
  def tasks
    @lists = List.all
    @list = List.friendly.find(params[:list_id])  <<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
    @items = Item.all
    @delegated_to_me = @items.where(:delegated_to == current_user.email)
    @delegated_by_me = current_user.items.where.not(delegated_to: "")
  end
```

When I try to view the page I get a `Record Not Found` error saying `Couldn't find List without an ID`.  From what I've seen on other SO posts usually this is a problem with a variable that isn't declared in the controller, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.  Can anyone help me troubleshoot?

ADDITIONAL INFO: ROUTES

```
      list_items GET    /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#index
                 POST   /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#create
   new_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
  edit_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
       list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
                 PATCH  /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                 PUT    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                 DELETE /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
           lists GET    /lists(.:format)                         lists#index
                 POST   /lists(.:format)                         lists#create
        new_list GET    /lists/new(.:format)                     lists#new
       edit_list GET    /lists/:id/edit(.:format)                lists#edit
            list GET    /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#show
                 PATCH  /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#update
                 PUT    /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#update
                 DELETE /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#destroy
   sharing_lists GET    /sharing/lists(.:format)                 sharing#lists
   sharing_tasks GET    /sharing/tasks(.:format)                 sharing#tasks
```

Comment: In this case, there is no List with the friendly id of whatever `params[:list_id]`  is. I would check the value of `params[:list_id]` first. If that ID is actually an integer, then it may just be that you need to call `List.find(params[:list_id])` with no `friendly`.

Comment: @steel, I know how to get the value of `@list` from my error message console (it's currently `nil`) but how do I check for `params[:list_id]`?

Comment: three ways at least. 1. `puts params[:list_id]` and check the server logs. or 2. Use something like `pry` or `byebug` just above the call in question or 3. Check the params sent by the HTTP request in the server log (simplest, but may be harder to find).

Comment: you can also simply `raise params` to see what's in there.  For debugging, I recommend better_errors and binding_of_caller.  Two gems that make it really easy to debug views

Comment: @liz how's your tasks route built? are you passing :list_id to it?

Comment: @mr_sudaca, I added the routes to the original post.

Comment: @Liz you need to pass list_id in your route, either `/sharing/lists/:list_id/tasks` or  via query string, like `/sharing/tasks?list_id=the_id`

Comment: @mr_sudaca, this page is intended to have items from many lists all on the same page. How would this work if the list was included in the route?

Comment: @Liz that's what you're asking on `List.friendly.find(params[:list_id])`. I assume that `friendly` is some kind of scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace @list with item.list

```
<h2 class="text-center">Delegated to Me</h2>
<% @deligated_to_me.each do |item| %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to list_path(item.list) do %>
      <%= item.name %>
    <% end %>
    (Deligated by <%= item.user_id %>)
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and remove the code from your controller.

```
@list = List.friendly.find(params[:list_id])
```

Comment: This still gives me `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` on the `@delegated_to_me` line.

Comment: You made a typo. Not "@deligated_to_me". It is  "@delegated_to_me".

Comment: Oh goodness.  All this code and I'm thwarted by spelling...  Thank you!